# User defined field in wit of tfs

Tags: tfs

In tfs for a work item type: can I define a user defined field common to all work item types in the collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes & No.

**Yes**

When you define a field in a WIT, for example `<FIELD name="My Field" refname="Company.MyField" ... />` you add that field to the collection.

You can see the fields in your collection by running:

```
witadmin listfieldfs /collection:http://tfs-server:8080/tfs/MyCollection
```

Any queries or reports you write or run against this collection can see this field. It appears in the Tfs_Warehouse database against your collection also.

**No**

You will have to add the field (the XML snippet above) to each work item type that you want to be able to store data against. If you are accessing it via the API, Excel, or something other than the work item then that is all you need.

**Global List**

You can share lists for the fields (such as a list of the teams for a "Team Detected By" field - for example) by creating a [Global List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404878%28v=VS.80%29.aspx).

Comment: I meant the 'no' part: many typical custom fields are shared between types and one has to edit them all when they change (e.g. suggestedvalues.

Comment: @Gerard added a bit more to my answer.